# Finding simpler implied formulas while preserving contradiction

Tags: logic, presburger-arithmetic

I have two Presburger formulas  A and B such that $A\land B \equiv \text{False}$. From these I need to find shorter formula $A'$ such that $A \rightarrow A'$ and $A' \land  B \equiv \text{False}.$ The size of A' does not have to be as short as is possible, but shorter is better. Is there a well-known process for calculating this? Ideally I am looking for an algorithmic simplifier that can handle largish formula (less than 10 variables, sum of products form with thousands of small products).

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are formula whatever ? If $B$ is *false*, let $A' := 0 = 0$; thus $\vdash 0 = 0$ and by the *tautology* : $\vdash B \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$ we may conclude : $\vdash A \rightarrow (0 = 0)$. But if $B$ is *false* also $(0 = 0) \land B$ is.

Comment: Both A and B are fixed but not specified in the problem.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The problem refers to formulas, not sentences, so I imagine free variables are allowed.  If the OP meant sentences, then you've essentially solved the problem --- take $A'$ to be $0=0$ 0r $0\neq0$ according to whether $A$ is provable or refutable. With free variables allowed, one could often get an $A'$ *simpler* than $A$ by quantifier elimination, but "simpler" (in this sense) might be very different from "shorter".

Comment: Yes, I intended for A and B to contain free variables.